# How many multiples of $18$ are there that are less than $3500$ and also $2$ more than the square of a natural number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So the expression of the number we want  will be $(n^2+2)\mod18$ .Now I was plugging different values of $n$ to get the answer.
Is there any trick to solve such problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need $n^2 \equiv 16 \pmod {16}$.  Clearly $4$ and $-4 \equiv 14$ satisfy this.  There may be others.  Just compute all the squares $\bmod 18$ to find out.  Then you need $n$ equivalent to one of these and less than $\sqrt {3500}\approx 59.2$

Answer (score 1):

You have $18m + 2 = n^2$ or $n^2 \equiv -2 \equiv 16 \mod 18$

Consider the equivalence classes modulo $18$ from $-8$ to $9$.  $(3k)^2 \equiv 9 k^2 \equiv 0, 1 \mod 18$ depending on whether $k$ is odd or even. So no multiple of $3$ is a solution.  $5^2 \equiv 7 \mod 18$ and $7^2 \equiv -5 \mod 18$. So the only possible solutions are $\pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8$.  ($0$ and $1$ obviously aren't).  $(\pm 2)^2 \equiv 4$ and $8^2 \equiv 64 \equiv -8 \mod 18$.  And $\pm 4$ is obviously a solution.

So $n = \pm 4 + 18k$ and $n^2 + 1 \le 3500$ so $n^2 \le 3598$ so $|n| < \sqrt {3598}$ so $|18k \pm 4| \le 59$.  So $ |18k| \le 63$ so $ k \le 3$.

So there are $4$ possible $k$s ($0...3)$ and 7 possible $n^2$s ($18k \pm 4$; $k = 0$ yield one  $n^2 = (\pm 4)^2$  but $k > 0$ yield two $n^2 (\pm 4 + 18k)^2$ and $7$ possible $n^2 + 2$.

i.e $k = 0$ then $n^2 + 2 = (4)^2 + 2 = 18$; $k = 1$ then $n^2 + 2 = \{14^2|22^2\} + 2 = \{198|486\} = \{11*18|27*18\}$ ; $k = 2 $ then $n^2 + 2 = \{32^2|40^2\} + 2 = \{1026|1602\} = \{57*18|89*18\}$ and $k=3$ then $n^2 + 2 = \{50|58^2\} + 2 = \{2502|3366\} = \{139*18| 187*18\}$

Comment: I think youn wanted  $18m = n^2 + 2$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   18m = n^2 + 2
      &\iff n^2 \equiv 16 \pmod{18} \\
      &\iff n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2} \; \text{and}\; n^2 \equiv 7 \pmod 9 \\
      &\iff n \equiv 0 \pmod 2  \; \text{and}\; n \equiv \{4, 5\} \pmod 9 \\
      &\iff n \equiv \{4, 14\} \pmod{18}
\end{align}

$59^2 + 2 = 3483 < 3500 < 3602 = 60^2 + 2$

So $n \le 59$.

\begin{array}{rrr}
n & n^2+2 & m=\dfrac{n^2+2}{18} \\
\hline
4  &   18 &   1 \\
22 &  486 &  27 \\
40 & 1602 &  89 \\
58 & 3366 & 187 \\
\hline
14 &  198 &  11 \\
32 & 1026 &  57 \\
50 & 2502 & 139 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   18m = n^2 + 2
      &\iff n^2 \equiv 16 \pmod{18} \\
      &\iff n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2} \; \text{and}\; n^2 \equiv 7 \pmod 9 \\
      &\iff n \equiv 0 \pmod 2  \; \text{and}\; n \equiv \{4, 5\} \pmod 9 \\
      &\iff n \equiv \{4, 14\} \pmod{18}
\end{align}

$59^2 + 2 = 3483 < 3500 < 3602 = 60^2 + 2$

So $n \le 59$.

\begin{array}{rrr}
n & 18m=n^2+2 & m=\dfrac{n^2+2}{18} \\
\hline
4  &   18 &   1 \\
22 &  486 &  27 \\
40 & 1602 &  89 \\
58 & 3366 & 187 \\
\hline
14 &  198 &  11 \\
32 & 1026 &  57 \\
50 & 2502 & 139 \\
\hline
\end{array}